# How merging 2 dataframes, irrespective of row's timestamp?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, timestamp

I would like to merge 2 dataframes with the same number of rows, irrespective of the timestamp of each row.
I simply want the data side by side (they are already sorted).
I tried to get rid off the timestamps, and then concatenate the dataframes, but without success.

Here is the 1st dataframe (as shown in a terminal):

```
                              Open     High
Timestamp
2019-04-11 04:00:00+00:00  5143.50  5191.64
2019-04-11 05:00:00+00:00  5180.18  5183.11
```

And here is the 2nd dataframe:

```
                            Open_2h   High_2h
Timestamp
2019-04-11 04:00:00+00:00     5100       5300
2019-04-11 06:00:00+00:00     5200       5400
```

Here is the result I would like to get:

```
                              Open     High  Open_2h  High_2h
Timestamp
2019-04-11 04:00:00+00:00  5143.50  5191.64     5100     5300
2019-04-11 05:00:00+00:00  5180.18  5183.11     5200     5400
```

So I tried following code:

```py
result = pd.DataFrame()
df1.reset_index()
df2.reset_index()
result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1 , sort=False)
```

I also tried:

```py
result = pd.DataFrame()
df1.reset_index()
df2.reset_index()
result = df1.join(df2)
```

I also tried beforehand to force a new index in df1 & df2:

```py
indexlist = list(range(0,2))
df1.loc[:,'Index'] = indexlist
df1.set_index('Index')
df2.loc[:,'Index'] = indexlist
df2.set_index('Index')
```

But timestamp data remains the index panda is relying on for the "join" or "concatenate" operation.

And with any of the above code, here is what I get:

```
                              Open     High  Open_2h  High_2h
Timestamp
2019-04-11 04:00:00+00:00  5143.50  5191.64     5100     5300
2019-04-11 05:00:00+00:00  5180.18  5183.11      NaN      NaN
2019-04-11 06:00:00+00:00      NaN      NaN     5200     5400
```

I tried merge_asof solution indicated here below, but with following data, duplicate lines appear:

df1

```
                           Open     High
Timestamp
2019-04-11 03:00:00+00:00  3000     3100
2019-04-11 04:00:00+00:00  4000     4100
2019-04-11 05:00:00+00:00  5000     5100
```

df2

```
                          Open_2h     High_2h
Timestamp
2019-04-11 00:00:00+00:00   0500         0600
2019-04-11 02:00:00+00:00   2500         2600
2019-04-11 04:00:00+00:00   4500         4600
```

I get:

```
                             Open     High  Open_2h  High_2h
Timestamp        
2019-04-11 03:00:00+00:00        3000     3100     2500     2600                                
2019-04-11 04:00:00+00:00        4000     4100     4500     4600
2019-04-11 05:00:00+00:00        5000     5100     4500     4600
```

Timestamp are still synchronized between both dataframe, and when no corresponding timpestamp is found in df2, previous values are copied.

Can someone help me getting rid of the timestamp of these dataframes to operate such a concatenation?

I thank you in advance for your help.

Best regards,

Pierre

Comment: You can assign the cols from `df2`
, `df1.assign(**df2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think the missing part in "reset_index()" was "inplace=True".
So following code does the job:

```py
df1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
result = df1.join(df2, sort=False)
```

Pffouuuhh
One afternoon on this! ;)

Thanks to all for your help!

Bests,

Pierrot

Answer (score 1):

this is [`merge_asof()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html)

```
pd.merge_asof(df1.reset_index(),df2.reset_index(),on='Timestamp').set_index('Timestamp')
```

---

```
                             Open     High  Open_2h  High_2h
Timestamp                                                    
2019-04-11 04:00:00+00:00  5143.50  5191.64     5100     5300
2019-04-11 05:00:00+00:00  5180.18  5183.11     5100     5300
```

if you dont want the index of second df to be considered:

```
df1.reset_index().combine_first(df2.reset_index(drop=True)).set_index('Timestamp')
```

---

```
                              High  High_2h     Open  Open_2h
Timestamp                                                    
2019-04-11 04:00:00+00:00  5191.64   5300.0  5143.50   5100.0
2019-04-11 05:00:00+00:00  5183.11   5400.0  5180.18   5200.0
```

Comment: Hi, I just tried, and indicated the result in my 1st post. It doesn't work, as timestamps between both dataframes still appear synchronized, and when no corresponding timestamp ins found in df2, values from previous timestamp are copied

Comment: @pierre_j did you also try the combine first solution?

Answer (score 0):

you could do

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1.reset_index(),df2.reset_index(),how='outer',left_on=['Timestamp'],right_on=['Timestamp'])
```

Comment: Hi, no, it does same as above: NaN are added for different timestamps

Comment: maybe it's because ` Timestamp ` is the index in your case, I just edited my solution

Comment: Yes I believe so, but "reset_index()" doesn't work: Timestamp is kept as index. I don't know how to get rid of it. I have just tried what you propose, and it still displays me NaN value where Timestamp don't match